# Sending emails in a local environment in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email, localhost, jakarta-mail

Is there any way to test how mails are sent using the [Mail Java Api](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview.html) for a Google AppEngine application in a **local environment**? The deployment to AppEngine takes too much time and it's tedious to lose so much time to test every change on the code.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question) I asked relative question today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875016 . So sending email doesn't work throw usual using Mail Java Api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this feature does not exist on the GAEJ SDK (In Python can be tested via sendmail).
Have a look to [this](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2425) feature request.